# HTML Form array in jQuery (Ajax)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have HTML elements like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fields[1][name]" placeholder="z.B. Speicherplatz" class="form-control">
<select name="fields[1][type]" class="form-control">
    <option value="number">Zahl</option>
    <option value="string">Zeichen</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="fields[1][default]" placeholder="z.B. 10" value="0" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="fields[1][minimum]" placeholder="Unbegrenzt" value="0" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="fields[1][maximum]" placeholder="Unbegrenzt" value="" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="fields[1][amount]" placeholder="z.B. <?=$nfo->placeholder(); ?>" value="<?=$nfo->format(0); ?>" class="form-control">

<input type="text" name="fields[2][name]" placeholder="z.B. Speicherplatz" class="form-control">
<select name="fields[2][type]" class="form-control">
    <option value="number">Zahl</option>
    <option value="string">Zeichen</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="fields[2][default]" placeholder="z.B. abc" value="abc" class="form-control">
<input type="text" name="fields[2][amount]" placeholder="z.B. <?=$nfo->placeholder(); ?>" value="<?=$nfo->format(0); ?>" class="form-control">
```

I need to create an array for a POST request, which should look like this in this example:

```
{
    1: {
        "name": "...",
        "type": "number",
        "default": "0",
        "minimum": "0",
        "maximum": "0",
        "amount": "100,00",
    },
    2: {
        "name": "...",
        "type": "string",
        "default": "abc",
        "amount": "100,00",
    },
}
```

So I need to parse the fields dynamically for each index. The elements from which I want to read the values are just textfields and select boxes. The elements are not static and can be different at every index.

How can I realize this with jQuery?

Comment: What is preventing you from reading the arrays on server from the array formatted `<input>` names?

Comment: I want to use Ajax

Comment: no problem...use `serialize()` and get arrays at server

Comment: No, this does not work. I need the data the client entered.

Comment: That's what serialize is for ... http://api.jquery.com/serialize/